# Does execv replace the current process like this?

Tags: process, posix, system-calls, execv

If in my code, I were to call execv, and then I had several lines of code after the call to execv, would those lines get executed, or would they not get executed, since whatever was started by execv replaces the current process?

Comment: I'm re-tagging this to remove C++ and add the Posix and system-calls keys.  There is nothing C nor C++ specific about execv*().

Answer (score 2):

They wouldn't be executed, unless the `execv()` call failed.  `execv()` completely replaces the program running in the process that calls it.

Comment: I noticed that this is usually the case, but if I run sleep with execv then it will continue to execute the following lines. Why is that?

Comment: @z-buffer, if `execv()` returns, it means it failed; if you check the return value you should find that it's -1.  Look at `errno` to find out why.  But it doesn't make much sense to fork and exec the sleep program anyway — the child process won't *do* anything except exist for awhile.  If you're making the parent wait for it to implement a delay, just use the `sleep()` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

They would not get executed, unless you forked the thread and called execv on just one of them.

Comment: Not even in that case.  POSIX says that "A call to any *exec* function from a process with more than one thread shall result in all threads being terminated and the new executable image being loaded and executed."